# Does new iPhone developer agreement pretty much kill CS5's feature to export to iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, flash

Will CS5's Packager for iPhone still be an option when CS5 comes out?  Or, will any apps submitted to the App Store be denied because of the new restriction that the app has to be written in Objective-C, C, C++, and/or AppleScript(?)?

Comment: Why did this question get downvoted? It seems quite reasonable to me. I'm going to vote it back up to zero, at least.

Comment: Thank you, Myk.  If someone downvotes, at least tell me why so that I can try to fix the reason for the downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second answer is correct: such applications will be denied.  Indeed, there has been ample [speculation](http://daringfireball.net/2010/04/iphone_agreement_bans_flash_compiler) that the very purpose of the new developer agreement is to stop Packager's spreading, because Apple really wants to limit iPhone apps to native ones.

Comment: Yes. Adobe isn't going to change anything in CS5 - you're still free to publish the .ipa files from Flash, and the ball is in Apple's court as to whether or not they'll be accepted.

Adobe has recently stated though that they're not really going to support this packager moving forward, which leads me to suspect that they had a sit-down with Apple and Apple basically told them to go to hell.

Comment: I am curious as to if Apple can detect if CS5 was used to compile the code?

Comment: @Allan: not from just using the app, but if you inspect the IPA binary you'll see lots of strings like flash.text.Textfield and so on. Packager doesn't try to obfuscate the apps origins or anything.

Comment: I actually saw a video that leaked out. Apparently there's an Adobe AIR app that lets you drag-and-drop any iPhone app onto it and if it was built in Flash it detects it instantly. Go figure. Wish I had saved that link. No guarantee that it's legit, but at least SOMEONE built it - so you know it's possible.

The binary itself carries all kinds of information inside of itself that gives it away instantly.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question has changed

**Special Update: September 9, 2010**

Apple’s recent announcement that it has lifted restrictions on its third-party developer guidelines has direct implications for the Packager for iPhone. The feature is available for developers to use today and Adobe will now resume development work on this feature for future releases.

http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/